# Products stop displaying in category page only on explicitly saving

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, stock, out-of-stock, associated-products

I have setup a CRON job for updating the **stock** in my Magento store regularly.

I have set the Magento configuration as not to show any product with respect to which all the associated products are out of stock. But it is not happening automatically.

The product still shows up on the product page and disappears only when I go to the product page in configuration and save it again explicitly.

Can someone kindly let me know why this is happening and how can I resolve this?

Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

All stock data is indexed in `cataloginventory_stock_status_idx` table.

Keep in mind, that if you make any changes in your `cataloginventory_stock_item` it won't work untill you make reindex process which you can initiate from magento backoffice or using for example `magerun`.

Another option is to regenerate it programatically:

```
$process = Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('cataloginventory_stock');
$process->reindexAll();
```

Comment: Ok. But, would saving the product from the backend explicitly again would do the reindexing too. Because once I did that the product used to disappear from the frontend immediately.

Comment: Yes - saving product from backend is always refreshing indexes (not only stock).
Be sure to set product with correct visibility and stock status.